# Entity Framework Core, Unit of Work and Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework-core, repository, unit-of-work

Having read numerous articles stating that putting a UOW and Repository pattern on top of an EF Core db context is not recommended, I am almost on board and am about to implement Services that gets IDBContext injected, in a new project of mine.

I say almost, as there's one feature I previously used that I don't understand how to implement without a repository.

In previous projects, I have used UOW and Repository patterns on top of EF and accessed them from a Service. The following method would be within a Repository and could be called thereafter by calling `uow.StudentRepository.Get(id)` from any Service.

```
public async Task<Student> Get(Guid id)
    {
        return await _context.Students
            .Include(x => x.Course)
            .Include(x=>x.Address)
            .Include(x => x.Grade)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

Without a Repository, querying from IDBContext, I would have to call...

```
_context.Students
            .Include(x => x.Course)
            .Include(x=>x.Address)
            .Include(x => x.Grade)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

...everytime I wanted to do this query. Which seems wrong as it would not be DRY.

**Question**

Could someone please suggest a way that I could declare this code in one place without a Repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a service. You can create a service like DbContext so that you can inject it into your controllers.

`IStudentService.cs`:

```cs
public interface IStudentService
{
    Task<List<Student>> GetStudents();
    // Other students methods here..
}
```

`StudentService.cs`

```cs
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public StudentService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Student>> GetStudents()
    {
        return await _context.Students
        .Include(x => x.Course)
        .Include(x=>x.Address)
        .Include(x => x.Grade)
        .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Then register the service into `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddScoped<IStudentService, StudentService>();
```

Now you can inject the service into any controller. Example:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StudentController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStudentService _studentService;
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public StudentService(DataContext context, IStudentService studentService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _studentService = studentService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> List()
    {
        return Ok(await _studentService.GetStudents());
    }
}
```

**Be sure** to create the service only if you will use it on multiple controllers and avoid fall into an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you for replying Guillermo.  I have a follow up question - at present GetStudents() is in the StudentsRepository and can be accessed from the Unit of Work  (uow.Students.GetStudents).  If I need to access GetStudents from another Service, I can easliy do it from the Unit of Work.

If this is moved to a StudentService and I wanted to access GetStudents from another Service (say an AdminService), would it be acceptable to inject StudentService into AdminService?

Comment: Yes, you can inject StudentService into other services, you can find more information about dependency injection here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Apologies for further question, I'm fine with DI, but what I was unsure about was if this was a sound way to architect as I wanted to avoid 'messy' service constructors i.e. `public PersonService(ILogService logService, ICourseService courseService, IAddressService addressService) `  Before I was able to access all these (as Repositories) from a Unit of Work.

Comment: I like this solution as your student service is essentially a segregated DAO class. Was a fan of the UOW repository pattern in the past and i think this is a good way forward.

Comment: How is the proposed service above different from a repository? The primary difference here seems to be in name only. This could just be a poor example, but the above quite literally looks the same as most repository classes I've encountered. A `Service` usually contains business logic, but above it behaves more as a 'pass-through' interface (which is not necessarily a good thing).